# I am using Java NetBeans. I want that if a user enters numeric value in text field of "Name", it must show an error using dialog box. How?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Java NetBeans. I want that if a user enters numeric value in text field of "Name", it must show an error using dialog box. How do I do it?

Comment: You can use a `DocumentFilter` to perform real time validation or you can use a regular expression to perform post validation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to understand your question better and provide you with better answers.